# select statement from a table ONLY if some of the fields were updated ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain, how I can create a select statement and fetch the data from a table, but only if particular fields were updated ?! Let's say I have:

```
select a, b, c, d , e, f
from table 1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.a = t2.a
```

I'm interesting if columns *d, e, f* were updated since yesterday let's say, than I want to include this row in my select statement, but if *d, e, f* were not updated since yesterday than ignore this row. In table1 I have a date field when the data was inserted (date_created) and the date field when it was updated (date_modified). The tricky bit is, that data in table1 might be updated by the users during the day, but not obligatory fields *d, e, f* , lets say user simply updated columns *a, b, c*. But date_modified column will show that the row has been updated. So I cannot rely purely on the date_modified column. My question is, is there any other way how to filter the data and get correct rows in return ? Triggers and stored procedures is not an option, ideally pure sql .. Any help?

Comment: Unless you add another column to track when the columns of interest are updated or you keep an audit of every column you simply cannot do what you are asking for.

Comment: Michael McGriff sorry mate, it is Oracle related ..

Comment: Sean Lange can you kindly provide with some useful links please? The first one is not an option I'm afraid, maybe worth try the second one, keep an audit. Will need to dig in that direction ... Thanks

Comment: One option, that may or may not be available to you as you can't use triggers or procedures, is to snapshot the table daily to a different table and then compare the two tables to find what's been changed.  Not exactly a great plan but trying to work with your constraints.

Comment: You could also restore yesterday's backup of the table to a new table and compare those two tables for variances.

Comment: Sounds good for me, it is definitely worth to try, thanks for the ideas !! Will post later with outcomes. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have flashback enabled and covering the time range you need? You could compare the rows that have been modified with a flashback query of the same table, if you have, without needing to explicitly restore a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear which columns belong to which table but one solution is to use a flashback query (provided you have sufficient undo retention to accommodate the 24 hour difference between queries).

An example of finding the differences on a table where columns `d`, `e` or `f` have changed from their value 24 hours ago is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM   table_name
                AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY
       ) p
       ON ( t.a = p.a
           AND ( t.d <> p.d OR t.e <> p.e OR t.f <> p.f ) );
```

Comment: MTO Sorry didn't see your post before I wrote my own answer. Looks pretty much good, will test it tomorrow and if it works, will mark your answer as correct. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Solution: Add an extra column (lets say Total) to the target table as a sum of columns *d, e, f* and update it for the first time. After that, if columns *d,e,f* were changed during the day, the sum of columns *d, e, f* will differ from the Total column, and you can simply filter it in where clause. 
Maybe it is not the most elegant solution, but it does the job. 
Thanks for yours ideas !!!